# VSTO 2010 with Visual Studio 11

Tags: vsto, compatibility, visual-studio-2012

I'm pretty much completely new to Visual Studio development (I did use VB6 back in the day, but that was ages ago), and I'm trying to get set up for developing COM Add-ins for Project 2010 and other MS Office 2010 applications. One of the things I'm trying to do now is [follow the tutorial on creating a custom tab using the Ribbon Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx).

However, I'm now stuck on step 2 of the "*Creating Actions Panes*" section:

> In the **Add New Item** dialog box, select **ActionsPaneControl**, and then
>   click **Add**.

Unfortunately, I'm using the free Visual Studio 11 Beta, and there's no "ActionsPaneControl" or "Actions Pane Control" in either the "Visual C#" or "Online" items list.

I've come across references to this control being part of the [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430) package, but there doesn't seem to be a VSTO package for VS11 yet. So will VSTO 2010 work with VS11, or will it just break VS11? What are my options here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions Pane Control is available only for Document level addins. The tutorial you are following is for Excel Workbook project (document level addin). Project 2010 has only Application level addins. For Application addins it is called Custom task pane.

For Application level addins use the UserControl and here is the tutorial for adding custom task pane.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/02/02/add-a-custom-task-pane-to-project-2010-norm-estabrook.aspx

Comment: thank you ... I've been trying to figure this out too.

Comment: me too.. docs suck for doing excel add-ins.. barely anything out there